# How to achieve the particular layout without distortion using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I need to design following design layout with help of Bootstrap 4:

[image]

My code :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-7"> A 
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">
           B 
        </div>

           </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small">
        <div class="col-md-12"> C
                      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My output

[image]

I am not getting my exact design layout. B and C part getting distorted. I have tried to set height for the container. But it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7 border"> A </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="border"> B</div>
    <div class="border"> C </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The asker didn't ask how to put a border on divs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kevin I am not asking about borders. I got distortion in my design (part B & C ).

Comment: I put the border just want to you can see where the div is. Please run the code snippet and click 'full page' button on the right corner and you will see it. We uses col-md that will change the layout like this when the space is smaller than md size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It will work.
html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 table-a">Table A</div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 table-b">Table B</div>    
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 table-c">Table C</div>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

for css

```
.table-a,.table-b,table-c{
    border: 5px solid #000;
}
.table-a{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.table-c{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

then you can format table-a accordingly for small devices using css

Answer (score 0):

When nesting you need to put both of the small columns into the same row as shown in the code snippet below.

Because both of the nested columns are `col-12`, they will stack on top of each other producing the desired effect.

The class `pl-md-4` on the parent column is used to give them a bit of left padding on screens that are `md` or larger.

The `mb-md-2` on the B column gives it a bit of margin-bottom on screens that are `md` and up.

Also, **make sure you put everything into a Bootstrap container**.

Click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 card">
            A 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 pl-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mb-md-2 card">
                    B 
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 card">
                    C 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But still i have faced some problems. I have placed Table in part A. I have not setting any height for it. I got output with height differences b/w A & B starting point.can you suggest any solution for this.

Comment: You need to describe (or show) exactly what you mean by "distortion". Distortion can mean a 1000 different things.

Comment: i mean alignment problem. look wise design layout is affected.

Comment: I have not the slightest idea what you mean. Read the following page a couple of times and make sure your issue can actually be understood and reproduced: [mcve]

Comment: In my Design layout, Part A, B are not in the same level. need to set height property?

Comment: What does it mean they are "not in the same level"??? They are perfectly on the same level. Read my previous comment and do what it says there.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have attached my output image in this query. In that image, left side and right side are not in the same level. I have designed by your suggestion.

Comment: What you show in that second image can only happen if you haven't actually used my code OR if you have some custom css that messes things up.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want B&C to grow with height of the table. Just use `h-100` on the contents of the the `col-md-7` and `col-md-5` so that they fill the height of the `.row`. As the table grows in height, so will B&C equally...

https://www.codeply.com/go/qex7szWyBb

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <table class="table h-100">
            ..
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="row text-white h-100">
            <div class="col-md-12 pb-3">
                <div class="bg-dark h-100">B</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="bg-dark h-100">C</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```